# Web Email Configuration

Tags: email, server, cpanel, dns-servers, configuration

I just created emails for my website from the cpanel. I then gave links to the cpanel webmail to each owner of the newly created mails. When they tried to login it returened invalid username and password combination. But on my own end they are all working very well.

please what could be the problem.
This is my first time of doing email configuration and cpanel in general.

I will be happy to provide any information that you might need.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is a little vague. As in most cases when a password is rejected.... either the user is trying to login to the wrong place with the right username/password, or they are trying to log into to the right place but with the wrong username/password. Are you (at your end) using the exact same process that the others are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who is your hosting company? I'm familiar with hostmonster which has unlimited hosting using virtual subdomains as addon domains. I give all my clients pop3 access and if they need web access I tell them to go to http://mail.theirdomain.com/ and their emails/passwords work.

The login is their complete email address / password

Make sure they are clicking on **WEBMAIL** to login to email and not the "Login to your account" link which takes them to the cPanel login. Tell them to click on the WEBMAIL link.

Answer (score 0):

do these clients have access to your cpanel?
also make sure that they have the correct mail servers.
also make sure they if they need or have ssl checked or unchecked depending on the service you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running cPanel your e-mail login page should be accessible via webmail.yourdomain.com
You will need to provide your clients with their account information which are the e-mail address and corresponding password to that e-mail.